# Counting duplicate, triplicate, etc. orders that can have multiple lines per order

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table of orders that can have multiple lines per order.  There are many occasions that duplicate, triplicate, etc. orders can be submitted.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for querying the table. I am no expert in T-SQL and I am having trouble coming up with a query to show the count for the number of duplicate/triplicate orders where `BotReady = 'Y'`.

Here is an example of the way our orders are stored in our table (`dbo.OrderTable`). The `PurchaseOrderNumber` is NOT unique so therefore we use `PurchaseOrderNumber` and `AccountNumber` as a super key.

| BotReady | PurchaseOrderNumber | AccountNumber | LineNumber | Quantity | UnitPrice | RequestedUOM | Style | Color | ProductType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | 217344 | 0026985 | 1 | 30 | 5.40 | EA | hwwtg | 11028 | H |
| Y | 217344 | 0026985 | 2 | 10 | 7.99 | SQF | lr105 | 00114 | C |
| Y | 217344 | 0026985 | 1 | 30 | 5.40 | EA | hwwtg | 11028 | H |
| Y | 217344 | 0026985 | 2 | 10 | 7.99 | SQF | lr105 | 00114 | C |
| N | 217344 | 0026985 | 1 | 30 | 5.40 | EA | hwwtg | 11028 | H |
| N | 217344 | 0026985 | 2 | 10 | 7.99 | SQF | lr105 | 00114 | C |
| Y | BD624919 | 0210995 | 1 | 158 | 12.80 | SHT | 551MR | 00122 | H |
| Y | BD624919 | 0210995 | 1 | 158 | 12.80 | SHT | 551MR | 00122 | H |
| Y | BD624919 | 0210995 | 1 | 158 | 12.80 | SHT | 551MR | 00122 | H |
| Y | BD624920 | 0210995 | 1 | 12 | 3.80 | SQY | 211MX | 00132 | H |
| N | BD624920 | 0210995 | 2 | 12 | 0.99 | EA | HA258 | 01088 | H |
| Y | 1269407 | 1911403 | 1 | 55 | 12.99 | BOX | HSMPR | 00150 | H |
| Y | 1269407 | 1911403 | 2 | 2 | 200.00 | ROL | TGJ88 | 01088 | C |
| Y | 1269407 | 1911403 | 3 | 1 | 10.00 | EA | 00000 | 00001 | R |
| Y | 1269407 | 1911403 | 1 | 55 | 12.99 | BOX | HSMPR | 00150 | H |
| Y | 1269407 | 1911403 | 2 | 2 | 200.00 | ROL | TGJ88 | 01088 | C |
| Y | 1269407 | 1911403 | 3 | 1 | 10.00 | EA | 00000 | 00001 | R |

The SQL should return 4 since there is 1 duplicate order for `PurchaseOrderNumber = 217344`, 2 duplicates for `BD624919`, and 1 duplicate for `1269407`.   So since each order can contain multiple lines per order that can affect how duplicates are counted.

For example, since PurchaseOrderNumber 1269407 has 3 lines in the order that appear twice it still only counts as 1 duplicate order (even if 2 of the 3 lines were duplicated) since they are all apart of the same order.

Comment: What do you mean by *super key*? You must explain what it takes to consider a row as a duplicate.

Comment: There isn't a primary key for the table.  We use the combination of the Account Number and Purchase Order Number to uniquely identify rows in the table (I believe it's also called a Candidate Key).

Comment: It is obvious from your sample data that Account Number and Purchase Order Number do not identify uniquely the rows of the table. So, what is a duplicate? Why there is only 1 duplicate for 1269407?

Comment: Each Order can contain multiple lines per order.  The column labeled LineNumber denotes that.  I'm looking for a way to count duplicate orders.  So since an order can can contain X amount of lines, if the same order appears in the table with the same X amount of lines, I need to count that as 1 duplicate.

Comment: so for example 12694407 there are 3 lines in that order.  Therefore it is 1 duplicate order.  And not 3 duplicate lines.  (I am not trying to count duplicate lines).

Comment: All these explanations (and more if needed) should be inside your question. So, edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @Rob, What if one line of `PurchaseOrderNumber` repeated but rest not? For example, line 1 is repeated, 2 and 3 not repeated. how do you wanna consider?

Comment: @Arun that could still be counted as a duplicate

Comment: @Rob, Look at the answer I have suggested. That will handle this.

Comment: @Arun Yes!  Thank you!  This did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` and `MAX` in sub-queries would do the trick:

If you want only number of duplicates to be displayed as `4`, the query would be:

```
select sum(tot) AS FINAL 
from
    (
    select PurchaseOrderNumber, max(cnt) as tot
    from
    (
        select 
             BotReady, 
             PurchaseOrderNumber,
             AccountNumber,
             Linenumber,
             count(*)-1 as cnt
        from t
        where botready='Y'
        group by 
             BotReady, 
             PurchaseOrderNumber,
             AccountNumber,
             Linenumber
             having count(*)>1
    ) as q
group by PurchaseOrderNumber
) as h
```

If you want which `PurchaseOrderNumber` had how many duplicates, the query would be:

```
select PurchaseOrderNumber, max(cnt) as tot
from
(
    select 
         BotReady, 
         PurchaseOrderNumber,
         AccountNumber,
         Linenumber,
         count(*)-1 as cnt
    from t
    where botready='Y'
    group by 
         BotReady, 
         PurchaseOrderNumber,
         AccountNumber,
         Linenumber
         having count(*)>1
) as q
group by PurchaseOrderNumber
```

Not much different, just final `SUM` is omitted.

Above queries would handle even if some of `linenumbers` are not repeated. Try that in fiddle link below.

see **DEMO** in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de990b1f9360e4d9644bf26aa603df51)*

Answer (score 0):

If i undertand well you want to detect duplicate in your table, the same data on all columns, this query can help you :

```
SELECT BotReady
    ,PurchaseOrderNumber
    ,AccountNumber
    ,LineNumber
    ,Quantity
    ,UnitPrice
    ,RequestedUOM
    ,Style
    ,Color
    ,ProductType
    ,COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.OrderTable
WHERE BotReady = 'Y'
GROUP BY BotReady
   ,PurchaseOrderNumber
   ,AccountNumber
   ,LineNumber
   ,Quantity
   ,UnitPrice
   ,RequestedUOM
   ,Style
   ,Color
   ,ProductType
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```